# Extend CiviCRM template in Extension

Tags: civimember, extension, templates, custom-templates

I am trying to extend the MembershipView.tpl which look like the image below. I have created an extension and added a MembershipView.extra.tpl file to my extension folder and placed it in Template>CRM>Membership>Form but the contents I have placed inside wont show in the membership view template.

[image]

Contents of my MembershipView.extra.tpl

```
{literal}
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert(5);
</script>
{/literal}
testing this text here
```

Thanking you

Imran

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: It seems that CiviCRM manages only one `.extra.tpl` file per template. If another extension adds an extra template, it can override yours.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a path problem or anything else, but in case of, it seems that CiviCRM manages only one `.extra.tpl` file per template. If another extension adds an extra template, it can override yours.

In this case, this answer works fine:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/33603/5794